# ASP.NET Core Data Protection with Azure Key Vault for containerized app deployment to Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-aks, azure-keyvault, data-protection

I have an ASP.NET Core app that I deploy in a containerized manner to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and when running just a single replica of the app - it is functional and works as expected.

However, when I run multiple replicas - I run into am error -  “Unable to protect the message.State” from the OIDC provider.
Upon further research I have figured out that using ASP.NET Core Data Protection as depicted here is the solution -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0#persisting-keys-when-hosting-in-a-docker-container

However - the above link does not expand upon the usage pattern of it while storing the key in Azure Key Vault. Assuming I have protected my keys in AKV how do I actually get to use it in my app? Is there sample or guidance on this aspect?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would recommend that the same client instance (With AddOpenIDConnect(...) is the same that also handles the callback from your Identity Provider (/signin-oidc). The state parameter that it sets when it first  redirects you to the identity provider must match the returned response (for security reasons).

To make sure that issued cookies in the users browser is valid all the time, you need to make sure:

1. All client instances uses the same data protection encryption key
2. The key is the same during redeployment.

You can for example store this key in Azure Key Vault, SQL-Server or somewhere else.

btw, I did a blog post about the Data Protection API [here](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault) and how you could store the key-ring in AKV as well.

I recently blogged about the state and nonce parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Extremely useful.
1. Ensuring same client instance - does anything explicit needs to be done in the containerized scenario like session affinity ?
2. In your post - the DPkey is programmatically stored in the KV. 
Is there a re possibility of pre-storing the DP Key manually in a KV and have it "used" by the app through a Kubernetes environment variable that gets populated by having the secret pulled down from KV?

Comment: You treat and handle the key-ring and the key-protection key separately. So in my blog post you store both in AKV, even though Microsoft for some reason does not "recommend it", there is also a ca 24Kb size limit.  Session affinity will probably be needed when you authenticate your users as the AddOpenIDConnect part needs to be the same during the authentication flow due to the state parameter that must be the same.